# How configure virtual host with port on Apache

Tags: angular, apache, virtualhost

I'm making a Universal Server-Side Rendering for project angular .I finished the tutorial and started a project with pm2 on port 4000 now I want to create a virtual host and set port the instance  for that project i trying that but Apache a down

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName  test.exemple.ma
        ServerAlias exemple.ma
        RewriteEngine  on
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) localhost:4000/$1 [P,L]
        ProxyPassReverse / localhost:4000
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi Adnane, it is unclear what is your question?

Comment: Did you enable `proxy` and `proxy_http` first?

`sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http`